# Replacing multiple occurrences of a word using sed in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have a requirement in unix to replace an occurrence of word with a space.
My File looks something like below. I need to replace |NA| with a space

File Format

```
1234|NA|NA|abcd|xyz
2345|NA|NA|NA|lmn
456|NA|abcd|xya|ggh
```

Expected Output

```
1234| | |abcd|xyz
2345| | | |lmn
456| |abcd|xya|ggh
```

I am using the following command but it only replaces the very first occurrence

```
sed 's/|NA|| |/g'
```

Comment: Your shown syntax is a syntax error.  You probably meant: `sed 's/|NA|/| |/'` (there's a slash in the middle that was missing from yours).  That should have changed the first _and third_ occurrences of `NA` in the second line, but not the second.  As well as the looping technique, you can also simply write the valid expression twice; that also does the job.

Answer (score 10):

While the `g` modifier does make "global" replacements, the replacements must be non-overlapping.  When overlapping replacements are required, one must loop:

```
$ sed ':a; s/|NA|/| |/g; ta' file.txt
1234| | |abcd|xyz
2345| | | |lmn
456| |abcd|xya|ggh
```

The above was tested on GNU sed.  For BSD (OSX) sed (Hat tip: Jonathan Leffler), the label `a` must occur only at the end of a command string:

```
sed -e ':a' -e ' s/|NA|/| |/g; ta' file.txt
```

#### How it works

- `:a` creates a label `a`.
- `s/|NA|/| |/g` performs the substitution that you want but only for non-overlapping instances of `|NA|`.
- `ta` tells sed to jump to label `a` if the preceding substitution command resulted in any changes to the line.  In this way, the substitution command is repeated as many times as necessary to replace every occurrence of `|NA|`.

Comment: BSD `sed` doesn't like the semicolon after the `:a`.  About the simplest fix that works is `sed -e ':a' -e ' s/|NA|/| |/g; ta'`, but if the `ta` was followed by more commands, that extra would need to be isolated in a separate `-e` argument.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks!  Answer updated with BSD solution.

Comment: Thanks John1024 and Jonathan Leffler. Both Solutions seem to work fine. However I am using Linux, will use the the solution by John1024..

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk for clarity, simplicity, portability, extensibility, etc., etc.:

```
$ awk '{while(gsub(/\|NA\|/,"| |"));}1' file
1234| | |abcd|xyz
2345| | | |lmn
456| |abcd|xya|ggh
```

First time through the loop the gsub() replaces all odd-numbered occurrences of the regexp and the 2nd time through it replaces any that are left. It will work as-is with any awk on any UNIX system.

Comment: @John1024 yup, you're right. Fixed, thanks. I thought I ran it under gawk but turns out I was using OSX awk which I'd have known better than to trust for testing!

Answer (score 0):

Failed utterly trying to escape the vertical bar. Then made an attempt without
having the vertical bar involved and it worked! Missed also that the
replacement is only one space, now corrected. This way the field is easily
expandable by adding space.

```
 awk '{gsub(/NA/," ")}1' file 
1234| | |abcd|xyz
2345| | | |lmn
456| |abcd|xya|ggh
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.